# How should I keep count in a Recursive function. Without tail recursion, or extra parameters

Tags: sml, ml

I have an ML programming assignment and in several of the functions, it would be useful to keep count. For example in one function I need to return a lists of indexes where an element appears.  I don't know how to track these things in recursion, as ever function call kills my count.  In the real world I would tack on a count variable, but that is not an option in school. Any tips?

Comment: Why is tail recursion not an option?

Comment: You need to pass to a function the information that the function needs to do its job. Why can't you create helper functions which have extra parameters? Such things are often done in ML. The definition of the helper function can be purely local to the function (using `let fun ... in...end)` so in that sense the overall function isn't cluttered by any extra parameters.

Comment: @Yawar, teachers orders.

Comment: @JohnColeman  I can use helper functions.  Should I just pass a count variable to the helper function.   For example my homer work says I must use the exact params for the original function, i.e. fun string2Int("1,2,3,4");  But I could pass "1,2,3,4" and a count variable to a helper function. 

I'll try it again with helper functions, and see how it goes. Thanks John

Comment: @JohnColeman So I just wrote a function using helpers, and it works great. Thanks buddy!

Answer (score 2):

If you can use a helper function, you can basically use tail recursion. Your teacher would not give you a recursion problem that forces you to use techniques other than pure recursion

The pattern with these functions is usually:

```
fun outer list =
  let
    fun inner param inner_list =
      (* use tail recursion here *)
  in
    inner initial_param list
  end
```

Comment: I will use let, in, end, on at least one problem to get a feel for it. 

By the way I'm jealous you got to hold the cup!  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Cheers  Sorry, just fixed up the syntax. I was probably thinking in OCaml when I wrote that initially.